# Webfont suddenly becomes bolded when it is smaller than a certain size

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

On this website I'm working on, I'm using this script font that has a lot of detail in it. The client pointed out that all the text using that font looks more bolded than it does in the design, losing a lot of detail. After a lot of digging I found that when the font is over 163px, it looks normal and you can see all the detail. But as soon as it goes 1px under that, it gets "bold", and I can't figure out why.

I've tried setting font-weight to 100, no change. I tried `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`, since I'm on a mac and I read that sometimes macs render text more boldly if you don't do this, but... That didn't change anything either.

I created a codepen to show my issue, but then I realized that `@font-face` doesn't support external URLs so you guys won't be able to see the font in action anyway. Here's a screenshot though, you can see the very plain html/css and the effect I'm seeing:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x3xs931l962524b/Screenshot%202019-10-16%2012.08.18.png?dl=0

Everything 163px and over looks normal, everything 162px and under looks bold. but whyyyy??

Edit: Apparently this is ONLY happening on some Macs in Chrome specifically. Could just be chrome rendering dumbness...?

Comment: @MrLister I tried grabbing the font from the site I'm working on to use in codepen, but apparently that's a nono, sourcing a font from an external url. From my testing and from what I read anyway.

Comment: https://codepen.io/maio/pen/rrKKjA

Comment: @MrLister Well in that case, have at it: 
https://codepen.io/matt_o_tron_5000/pen/gOOMeZN

Comment: The URLs to the font files result in 404.

Comment: The URL for the font file as used on the site is https://staging-beautybyearthcom.kinsta.cloud/app/themes/bbe_theme/dist/fonts/Northwell-Alt_adfc61cd.woff2, so I forked the codepen: https://codepen.io/MrLister/pen/XWWKBoe

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two lines there though. What browser are you using?

Comment: @MrLister I'm using Chrome on a 15" Macbook Pro. I just tested on Safari and Firefox and actually I'm not having the same issue on those browsers... So it could be a Chrome rendering issue?

Comment: I don't know; I can't test on a Mac, only on Linux and Windows, and I don't see the issue in any browser I've tested so far. Sorry.